# Passing string array from ASP.NET to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json

I am trying to call the server side from JavaScript and then pass a string array back to JavaScript, but running into problems.

```
// Call the server-side to get the data.
$.ajax({"url" : "MyWebpage.aspx/GetData",
        "type" : "post",
        "data" : {"IdData" : IdData},
        "dataType" : "json",
        "success": function (data)
        {
            // Get the data.
            var responseArray = JSON.parse(data.response);

            // Extract the header and body components.
            var strHeader = responseArray[0];
            var strBody = responseArray[1];

            // Set the data on the form.
            document.getElementById("divHeader").innerHTML = strHeader;
            document.getElementById("divBody").innerHTML = strBody;
        }
});
```

On the ASP.Net server side, I have:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static object GetTip(String IdTip)
{
    int iIdTip = -1;
    String[] MyData = new String[2];


    // Formulate the respnse.
    MyData[0] = "My header";
    MyData[1] = "My body";

    // Create a JSON object to create the response in the format needed.
    JavaScriptSerializer oJss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    // Create the JSON response.
    String strResponse = oJss.Serialize(MyData);

    return strResponse;
}
```

I am probably mixing things up, as I am still new to JSON.

UPDATE with error code:

```
Exception was thrown at line 2, column 10807 in     http://localhost:49928/Scripts/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
```

0x800a03f6 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character

Stack trace:
parse JSON[jquery-1.7.2.min.js] Line 2

What is my problem?

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: See my edit in the question.

Comment: Why the deduction in points?

Comment: Looks like the call to JSON.parse isn't happy with the format of the input data. What's the value of `data.response`?

Comment: @SarahWeinberger do not know who down voted you but try to put as much information as possible in your question otherwise you will end up getting thumbs down :)

Comment: I started off JavaScript to Server to JavaScript access via PHP, not ASP.Net, so I was familiar with things that way.  There is much more code and discussions with JavaScript to PHP than ASP.Net.  Yes, I saw posts, just not returning data.  I guess the only thing that could be added to my code or ajakblackgoat's response for others (or myself) is what about multiple variables to the server.  I just did one, IdTip.  I assume a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your ajax call script to :

```
// Call the server-side to get the data.
$.ajax({
    url: "WebForm4.aspx/GetTip",
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify({ IdTip: "0" }),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        // Get the data.
        var responseArray = JSON.parse(data.d);

        // Extract the header and body components.
        var strHeader = responseArray[0];
        var strBody = responseArray[1];

        // Set the data on the form.
        document.getElementById("divHeader").innerHTML = strHeader;
        document.getElementById("divBody").innerHTML = strBody;
    }
});
```

Note that I added `contentType: 'application/json'` and changed

```
var responseArray = JSON.parse(data.response);
```

to

```
var responseArray = JSON.parse(data.d);
```

Comment: Ajakblackgoat's response was the answer with one change.  I had to change 'IdTip: "0"' to 'IdTip: IdTip', as the JavaScript variable IdTip had the primary key.  It is interesting that the first argument did not need quotes around it to indicate the parameter. (continued second comment)

Comment: I did not realize at the beginning, but I never hit a breakpoint in the C# code.  I honestly thought that the code executed and just that Visual Studio was being obnoxious.  The same was true for JavaScript inside the success code.  Further debugging this morning yielded that the b variable was my HTML document code that JSON tried to parse.  I received one crash every time the $.ajax processed after returning from the JavaScript procedure, hence no stack trace.  Ajakblackgoat nailed the problem, not that I understand the why on his changes.  Both were needed.  Thanks!

Comment: JSON.stringify will take care of converting the parameter names to string. And don't forget the `contentType` must be set to `'application/json'`

Answer (score 1):

This s purely out of guess work. But see if this is what you are getting:-
In your `Ajax` call, your data type is json and looking at the method you are returning a json string. So you do not need to do JSON.parse(data.response). Instead just see if the below works for you. Also i dont see a `response` object in your Json, instead it is just an array. So it must be trying to parse `undefined`

```
 var strHeader = data[0];
 var strBody = data[1];
```

Comment: After implementing ajakblackgoat's code, I started receiving success messages.  I guess I should suspect that if I do not receive a success message or hit a breakpoint, then I am really not getting there and the problem lies elsewhere.  Nonetheless, I decided to see what data[0] and data[1] returns.  They returned "undefined".  I placed alert statements to check and also hit the breakpoint.  Both showed "undefined".  I placed alert("data[0]"+data[0]) statement.  When I did the same using ajakblackgoat's parsed data, I got the proper value returning.